# loop through Array and perform arithmetic on nil value in Lua

Tags: arrays, math, lua, null

I'm pretty new to lua and already stared messing around with lua. I have written the following script to print out my distance and angle to every available object in the constructer with the help of an array but there is a big problem in my way:

```
me = {'["game.exe"+2A]','["game.exe"+A8]','["game"+6A8]'}

botallx = {'["game.exe"+01]','["game.exe"+02]','["game.exe"+03]',
'["game.exe"+04]','["game.exe"+05]','["game.exe"+06]','["game.exe"+07]',
'["game.exe"+08]','["game.exe"+09]','["game.exe"+10]','["game.exe"+11]',
'["game.exe"+12]'}

botally = {'["game.exe"+31]','["game.exe"+32]','["game.exe"+33]',
'["game.exe"+34]','["game.exe"+35]','["game.exe"+36]','["game.exe"+37]',
'["game.exe"+38]','["game.exe"+39]','["game.exe"+30]','["game.exe"+31]',
'["game.exe"+32]'}

botallz = {'["game.exe"+51]','["game.exe"+52]','["game.exe"+53]',
'["game.exe"+54]','["game.exe"+55]','["game.exe"+56]','["game.exe"+57]',
'["game.exe"+58]','["game.exe"+59]','["game.exe"+50]','["game.exe"+51]',
'["game.exe"+52]'}

function sight_angle()
     if (isKeyPressed(VK_E)) then

     for i=1, 12 do
     if (botallx[i] ~= nil or botally[i] ~= nil or botallz[i] ~= nil ) then
     vecX=readFloat(me[1])-readFloat(botallx[i])
     vecY=readFloat(me[2])-readFloat(botally[i])
     vecZ=readFloat(me[3])-readFloat(botallz[i])

     distance=math.sqrt(math.pow(calcZ,2)+math.pow(calcX,2))

     angleX=math.deg(math.atan2(calcZ, calcX))

     print ("current distance is " .. distance)
     print ("current angle is " .. angleX)
     else --One of the botallx, botally, botallz value was nil
     print ("Can't perform calculations due to a nil value")
     end
     end
end
```

theses addresses called ["game.exe"+...] contain a float value, but some of the objects in the container of botally, botallx and botallz are nil or have nil values. So when I execute the script then the array for i=1 to 12 starts calculating the first one and gives me the angle and distance, but keeps calculating until it hits an object from the container that has a nil value and then doesn't want to carry on calculating the other objects.

Example: object 1,3,6 inside botally, botallx and botallz have values, everything else is nil.
it starts calculating the first one...gives out the distance and angle, but then stops at the second and starts complaining that the calculation can't be performed because of a nil value, so it jumps back to the first object and gives me the dist and angle of it again.

But I want it to jump over that second empty nil object and continue with the 3rd object, which has a value and print the distance and angle for me, then jump over the empty 4th and 5th one and calculate the 6th one and after that, it can jump back to the first one again because the rest from 7 to 12 is nil.

but it doesn't want to do this....can somebody help me?

Comment: Currently, there seems to be a problem with your table constructions. Check your single quotes (`'`), since there are some unmatched ones. 
The way you are showing your script here (ignoring errors in construction), there are no `nil` values in your tables.

Comment: Then there is also a strong feeling that you should do this different. You said there are float values (so numbers) in your tables, but you decide to use strings to store these values. This seems very strange.

Comment: oh i see, i fixed the single quotes. these strings inside the tables are actually pointeradresses that point to specific adresses wich contains a float value.

Comment: Do you use lua embedded in, say c++? In pure lua, there are no pointers, so what are you exactly doing? And even if you needed the offset for pointer addresses, it would still be easier to store them as a number, not as strings. Perhaps you can show some code. Where are you getting the offsets from?
And btw, you haven't fixed the single quotes, look at the syntax highlighting. Your code beneath the tables is red (which is a string).

Comment: Sorry I rechecked it again...now it should be fixed with the quotes. I use LUA embedded in a Programm called Cheat Engine to use pointers. I want to print out my distance and angle to the all the current bots displayed in the game

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in lua, you should use `~= nil` to check if a value is `nil. So you can modify your code like this:

```
  for i=1, 12 do
    --Do the following calculations only if botallx or botally or botallz        
    -- are not nil
    if (botallx[i] ~= nil or botally[i] ~= nil or botallz[i] ~= nil ) then
       vecX=readFloat(me[1])-readFloat(botallx[i])
       vecY=readFloat(me[2])-readFloat(botally[i])
       vecZ=readFloat(me[3])-readFloat(botallz[i])

       distance=math.sqrt(math.pow(calcZ,2)+math.pow(calcX,2))

       angleX=math.deg(math.atan2(calcZ, calcX))

       print ("current distance is " .. distance)
       print ("current angle is " .. angleX)
    else --One of the botallx, botally, botallz value was nil
       print ("Can't perform calculations due to a nil value")
 end
```

Alternatively the above if statement can also be written like this:

```
if (botallx[i] not nil or botally[i] not nil or botallz[i] not nil )
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, somehow it did not changed anything...the script still behaves the same way as before.

Comment: it stops calculating when it hits a nil value and does not print out the other calculated objects.

for i=1, 12 do
--obj 1 is nil, obj 2,3,4 not nil, obj 5-12 is nil, it  prints the error

Error:[string "me = {'["game.exe"+01"]:46: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value,

only when i change the array from a point where it has a value at the beginning then it proceeds to give out answers.

for i=2, 12 do
--obj 1 is nil, obj 2,3,4 not nil, obj 5-12 is nil it does print the answers

Comment: The code you've posted is not the same as the one in my answer. You're not checking if all objects are not nil but only if objects 2,3,4 are not nil. So if obj1 is nil, code flow will continue in the body of if and as a result it'll try to "perform arithmetic on a nil value" (obj1).

Comment: I didn't edited my code that posted here...thats right, but i changed my code in LUA. and i still have the same issue as before

Comment: okay now it gots very weird....when i change the counter for "i=1, 12 do" to "i=0, 12 do" i now get the error message ("Can't perform calculations due to a nil value") for the 0 object, and the error  Error:[string "me = {'["game.exe"+01"]:46: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value for the 1st obj that is nil

Comment: That's not weird. This happens because in lua arrays are not 0-based indexed but they start from 1. In other words `botallx[i]` when `i=0` will throw an error because lua arrays start from 1. 
So don't change the starting point of i keep it as it is. Are you still facing problems with the code?

Comment: okay i keep it from 1, 12. yep...still facing the same problem as before, strange...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `and` rather than `or` here. With `or`, you're checking that at least one of them exists, and then using the ones that don't exist anyway.

```
if (botallx[i] ~= nil and botally[i] ~= nil and botallz[i] ~= nil ) then
```

Alternatively:

```
if botallx[i] and botally[i] and botallz[i] then
```

Although those `botall` addresses will always be non-nil the way you've set up your tables.

What are `calcX` and `calcZ`? **Did you mean `vecX` and `vecZ` there?** That's your nil arithmetic exception if so. If you didn't know, an undeclared variable has a nil value instead of causing an "unknown symbol" error like in most other languages.

Assuming that `calcX` problem is just a copy/paste error, you might need to do some nil checks on those `readFloat(...)` calls.

```
function sight_angle()
    if (isKeyPressed(VK_E)) then
        local meX = readFloat(me[1])
        local meY = readFloat(me[2])
        local meZ = readFloat(me[3])
        if not meX or not meY or not meZ then
            print ("Can't perform calculations due to a nil value")
            return
        end
        for i=1, 12 do
            -- Ditch the botall nil checks
            local bX = readFloat(botallx[i])
            local bY = readFloat(botally[i])
            local bZ = readFloat(botallz[i])
            
            if bX and bY and bZ then   
                local vecX=meX-bX
                local vecY=meY-bY
                local vecZ=meZ-bZ

                -- Assuming calcX and calcZ meant vecX and vecZ
                local distance=math.sqrt(math.pow(vecZ,2)+math.pow(vecX,2))

                local angleX=math.deg(math.atan2(vecZ, vecX))

                print ("current distance is " .. distance)
                print ("current angle is " .. angleX)
            else
                print ("Can't perform calculations due to a nil value")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Of course, I have absolutely no idea what any of these things do! Is this a Cheat Engine plugin? I'm just basing this on what I can see in your code snippet.